# Split Long String by String Array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a hex input string of `"0000095700012A27"`. I want to split the input string based on my textbox input which I have coded as following:

```
String txtbox_input = "-2,4,-4,4,2";
String pattern = ",";
String[] splitters = Regex.Split(txtbox_input, pattern);
```

It will split based on my `txtbox_input` and basically, I want my output to be:

```
00,0009,5700,012A,27
```

Along the way, is it possible to determine the `txtbox_input` as if it's negative, it will skip the conversion? As I wanted my split data to be converted as following if the number is positive.

```
data = Convert.ToUInt16(splitdata, 16);
```

Comment: What exactly do `-` signs mean in your input? What is the expected output for your `-2,4,-4,4,2`?

Comment: What have you done so far to achieve it?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev the negative sign is for the indicator to or no to complete the conversion after the split.

Comment: Does it need to be regex rather than just using substring? Also why have your format in a string rather than having a proper class with an int and a bool on (or something along these lines) to save having to do complicated parsing to work out what you need to do?

Comment: @FaizanRabbani previously, I able to get the specific length of 4 eg. `012A` as the data then convert it back to decimal. But I tend to increase the size of data collection and convert it based on my need.

Comment: Why not a simple for loop through your split txtbox_input array, getting a substring based on the absolute value - no need for regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case we want to *ignore* all minuses, and thus return consequent chunks of `2, 4, 4, 4, 2` characters long

```
  String source = "0000095700012A27";
  String txtbox_input = "-2,4,-4,4,2";
  String pattern = ",";

  var data = txtbox_input
    .Split(new string[] { pattern }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(item => Math.Abs(int.Parse(item))) // Math.Abs - ignoring minus
    .Select(length => {
      string item = source.Substring(0, length);
      source = source.Substring(length);

      return item;
    })
 // .Select(item => Convert.ToUInt16(item, 16)) // if you want UInt16 items
    .ToArray(); // Let's have an array of chunks

  Console.Write(string.Join(",", data));
```

Outcome:

```
  00,0009,5700,012A,27
```